# Getting base Python interpreter in Makefile on Windows or POSIX

Tags: python, windows, macos, makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to make a `Makefile` that has the path to system Python in an environment variable, that works on Windows and POSIX systems.

The below works on macOS and Windows WSL, but if you have a virtual environment activated, it returns the `venv`'s path (not system Python's path):

```
SYSTEM_PYTHON = $(shell which python3)
```

The below works regardless of `venv` being activated, but it doesn't work on Windows (due to Windows not using `bin`, and using `\\`):

```
SYSTEM_PYTHON = $(shell python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.base_prefix)")/bin/python3
```

How can I make a `SYSTEM_PYTHON` env var that works on both Windows and POSIX, regardless if a virtual environment is previously activated?

Comment: It's not very clear what you want to achieve. Can you give post the expected path and the actual path you got ?

Comment: I'm just curious how those two end up differing.  and busy figuring that out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works on my windows even if i had an venv

```
ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
    SYSTEM_PYTHON = $(shell python -c "import sys; print(sys.base_prefix)")\\python.exe
else
    SYSTEM_PYTHON = $(shell python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.base_prefix)")/bin/python3
endif

all:
    @echo "System Python is located at: $(SYSTEM_PYTHON)"
```

Comment: `shell python` for Windows and `shell python3` for non-Windows is a good call, that was a piece I was missing, thanks